# Can I include another file in fstab

Tags: fstab

Can I include another file in my `fstab` file?

I.e. can I have `fstab` execute lines from another file at an arbitrary point, and then return to the main file when completed?

Comment: If you have so many mount points that this is an issue, you're probably looking for an [automounter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automounter) such as [autofs](http://www.autofs.org/).

Comment: Related question from Ask Ubuntu: [Why can't mount read files in “/etc/fstab.d/”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/168290/74792)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally not, but with newer versions of `mount`/`swapon`/`fsck`... on Linux (from util-linux 2.19) at least, you can have more files (with `.fstab` extension) in `/etc/fstab.d`. So you can have a `/etc/fstab.d/00_header.fstab`, `/etc/fstab.d/50_middle.fstab`, `/etc/fstab.d/99_end.fstab`.

Another approach if all you want is `mount -a` to run some command is have an entry with your *own* filesystem type and create a `/sbin/mount.own` that does the work for you.

Note that recent versions of `Ubuntu` have that `mountall` that might get in the way.

Also note that some distributions process mounts in several stages using `-t fstypes`, which you may need to take into account as well.

Answer (score -1):

I have never seen a Unixy system with such an `fstab(5)`-setup. Look at `mount(8)` for the gory details of what can be done at mount time.

What do yu want this for? If *really* useful in more than a narrow range of usecases it just might get implemented...

Comment: I have a lot of computers that mount the same nfs, I want to centralize the fstab life relating to that nfs (so I don't have to change it on all machines when it changes)

Comment: Do you have an svn or another version control system?
Or if you have config management like salt, chef, puppet, ..etc?

In the case of svn, you can have a script that checks out from svn, and then builds/appends to `/etc/fstab`, monitor it periodically, compare from svn.
If you have a config management, you can build your fstab from a template. For example, in salt, you can use jinja2 template to build the mounts portion of your `/etc/fstab`, and that would also prevent accidental typing errors.